# Open-source echo server

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, echo

Does anyone know any open-source echo server? I know I could write one by myself, but I'd like something more fancy with ability to listen on certain port(s), send keep-alives etc. so developing this myself would take likely hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

- [that little (21 line) python demo program `A simple echo server`](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html)
- [echoserver @ google code](http://code.google.com/p/softenido/wiki/echoserver)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

inetd has echo built in. Uncomment it in /etc/inetd.conf

Comment: Goog point. However I need it working on Windows, cygwin at least.